# junction tables in Breeze JS many to many. How to get data.results

Tags: sql, database, breeze

I'm working on my first Breeze Angular project (.NET). I'm slowly getting there but for the last 2 days I've been stuck with the following problem.

I have 3 Tables.

[Products] 1>m [ProductCategory] m<1 [Categorys]

ProductCategory  is a Junction/Link table that has 
ProductID and CategoryID as Foreign keys. Very simple.

I need to generate a list of Categorys where ProductId = 3

any Idea how I do this with Breeze EntityQuery?

What would the Breeze Query look like?
This is as far as I have got.

```
 var query = breeze.EntityQuery 
.from("Categorys") 
.expand(???)
.where("ProductCategory.ProductID", "==", 3);
```

All three tables are correctly Modeled eg

```
public class Product_Category
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
     [Required]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public Category Categories { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductID")]
    public Product Products { get; set; }

}
```

The simple SQL statement would look like:-

```
     SELECT  ProductCategory.ProductID, ProductCategory.CategoryID,
     Categorys.CategoryName FROM            
                       ProductCategory INNER JOIN
                              Categorys ON 
ProductCategory.SubCategoryID = Categorys.SubCategoryID 
WHERE    (ProductCategory.ProductID = 3)
```

I realise this is a very common requirement but try as I might I cannot find a solution.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Dominic here is a solution to the above. In case anybody else is as thick as me.

BREEZE

```
 var query = breeze.EntityQuery
.from("Products_Categories")
.expand("Categories")
.where("ProductID", "==", parseInt(prodid));
```

Angular View:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in ProductCategory">
    <div data-ng-repeat="sub in item.Categories">
        <span ng-show="sub.CategoryName.length">{{sub.CategoryName}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do query like

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery 
.from("Categorys") 
.expand(???)
.where("ProductCategory.ProductID", "==", 3);
```

But I'm sure you can do query like

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery
.from("ProductCategory")
.expand("Categories")
.where("ProductId", "==", 3);
```

Then you would have to iterate through ProductCategories and then through Categories within. I'm not 100% sure of the syntax because for some strange reason expand on client side didn't work for me in the past and got used to writing .Include in breezeController, but logic should be the same.

Comment: That great Dom! simple as that hey? I think where i got lost was with the nested loop on the client. Thanks a lot it works well.